# How to add entity listener to entity imported from library in SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, entitylisteners

In SpringBoot project, I am using entities from third party libraries and I want to bind some **entity listener** (that I wrote) to it.

However, I can't edit that entity and add @EntityListeners annotation to it, so is **there any other way to bind my custom listener to entity imported from library?**

Comment: do you have a solution after 1 year 7 months ?